# Loss Policy Gradient - Reinforcement Learning

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient-descent

I am training my network using policy gradient and defining the loss as:

```
self.loss =  -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(OUTPUT_NN)* self.REWARDS))
self.opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss)
```

What I do not understand is that the loss function is sometimes positive other times negative. I do not understand this flip in the signal. For me, it should always be negative as I have the minus in front of the `tf.reduce_mean.`

Example:

```
Train-> Reward: 0.257782, Hit Ration: 0.500564, True Positive: 0.433404, True Negative: 0.578182, loss: 6.698527 
Train-> Reward: 0.257782, Hit Ration: 0.500564, True Positive: 0.433404, True Negative: 0.578182, loss: -11.804675
```

Is that possible or am I doing something wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into much details, you need to calculate the gradient of an equation:

[image]

where [image: a_t] is the action taken at time t, [image] is the state at t and [image] is the discounted reward (or not discounted up to you) again for t.

So at time t, you know action [image: a_t], which you can represent as a one-hot encoded vector, right? Now if you look at the first term of your loss:

[image]

this actually a log likelihood or cross-entropy. So your equation should look like:

```
self.loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=ONE_HOT_ACTIONS, logits=OUTPUT_NN),REWARDS))
self.opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss)
```

Comment: Hi @asakryukin, thanks for your answer. I have a question. When you say the actions at time t I know and you use them in the cross-entropy in the "labels". The thing is I do not have labels in my training, I dont get this point very well. Could you kindly explain me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlexGomes the labels are your one-hot encoded actions and logits - outputs of your network. Suppose you have possible actions left (0) and right (1). So for some state s, where you took left and your net output was [0.9,0.1] -> label for your cross-entropy [[1,0]] and logits [[0.9,0.1]]

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I will try it here. Just one more question. Is there any other way to do it without the cross entropy? @asakryukin

Comment: @AlexGomes not for policy gradients. You can use Q-learning algorithms instead, there you don't need it.